# SSH fork and children

Tags: ssh, timeout, fork

I have a program where i ssh into a server and gets data. Here is the code... I fork it and the child executes the query and the parent waits for the child for a predetermined amount of time (in function timeout) and then kills the child. I did that part because sometimes, i am not exactly sure why, but the ssh connection stops and doesnot exit. That is there is a "ssh -oConnectTimeout=60 blah blah" in the processes list for a long and the timeout function doesnt seem to work. What am i doing wrong here? The last time this problem occured, there was an ssh in process list for 5 days and still it didnot timeout and the program had stopped because it was waiting for the child. There are those extra wait() functions because previously i was getting a lot of defunct processes a.k.a zombies. So i took the easy way out..

```
c = fork();
if(c==0) {
    close(fd[READ]);

    if (dup2(fd[WRITE],STDOUT_FILENO) != -1)
        execlp("ssh", "ssh -oConnectTimeout=60", serverDetails.c_str(), NULL);
    _exit(1);

}else{
    if(timeout(c) == 1){
        kill(c,SIGTERM);
        waitpid(c, &exitStatus, WNOHANG);
        wait(&exitStatus);
        return 0;
    }
    wait(&exitStatus);
}
```

This is the timeout function.

```
int timeout(int childPID)
{
int times = 0, max_times = 10, status, rc;
while (times < max_times){
    sleep(5);
    rc = waitpid(childPID, &status, WNOHANG);
    if(rc < 0){
        perror("waitpid");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(WIFEXITED(status) || WIFSIGNALED(status)){
        /* child exits */
        break;
    }
    times++;
}

if (times >= max_times){
    return 1;
}
else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIGTERM just asks for a polite termination of the process. If it's got stuck, then it won't respond to that, and you'll need to use SIGKILL to kill it. Probably after trying SIGTERM and waiting a little while.

The other possibility is that it's waiting for the output pipe to the parent process to not be full - maybe there's enough output to fill the buffer, and the child is waiting on that rather than the network.

Comment: is it possible that this has anything to do with process groups? what i thought was if i call execlp, and once ssh connects, its a different process and the one i terminate wont terminate the actual process, that is the ssh.. just a thought...

Comment: one more thing. When i use ps ax and use kill 1234, where 1234 is the pid of ssh, it works.. and the program continues in the next loop.. isnt using just kill equal to SIGTERM?